# Calculate Thread ID in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I write my code, and I use one block of size 8*8. I use this formula to define the index of a matrix:

```
int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;  
int idy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
```

And to check it, I put the `idx` and idy in a 1D array, so I can copy it to host to print it out.

```
if (idx<N && idy<N) 
{
    c[idx]=idx;
    d[idx]=idy;
}//end if
```

The strange thing is that `idy` always give me 3!
Can anyone help to resolve it?

Comment: The value of all elements of `d` is really random. 
What the value of `N`?? imxp `N%8 == 3`. no? ...

Comment: thank you Yappie for your replay. First time I thought it because of the speed between thread , and may thread 3 is the fastest. But I run it many times but still give me 3. N is the block size, in this case 8.

Comment: How are you initializing your kernel call? What values did you use for block/grid dimensions?

Comment: The picture is very vague in your question. If you can post your complete code I can go through it. For example the data type of 'c' and 'd' can make the difference, the execution parameters as well as CPU-side code.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely undefined behavior. The condition is true for *every* thread. So 8 threads (along y dimension) are trying to write into a *single* location. The value being written can be anything any one of those.

Just because you are seeing a particular value does not mean it is consistent behavior that can be explained.

If you really need to see proper results I suggest you try the following

```
id = idy * N + idx;
if (idx<N && idy<N) 
{
    c[id]=idx;
    d[id]=idy;
}//end if
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test code:

```
d[idx]=idy;
```

should probably be:

```
d[idy]=idy;
```

?

Comment: Even that won't help - it should be `idx + gridDim.x * idy` in both cases to have every thread write a unique value to global memory

Comment: thank you Paul , yes it give me another output. But how is that ?!

Answer (score 0):

The thread ids are solved correct. But if you want to fill unique identifiers of each thread you must create `c` and `d` arrays with size `N*N` and fill its like this

```
if (idx<N && idy<N) 
{
   c[idy*gridDim.x+idx]=idx;
   d[idy*gridDim.x+idx]=idy;
}
```

In your code.. For example `N = 16` and you have `idx = 2`. and this value the `idx` has for `idy = 1, 2, ... 16` and every if this 16 threads put `2` into c[2].

For d. Every of this 16 threads with `idx = 2` put its `idy` in `d[2]` and result depends from order of threads execution.

Comment: Threads are numbered in column major order, not row major order, so you are probably using the wrong indexing formula in your answer.

Comment: Thank you Yappie for your answer.. I use this index and c gives me all 0's.. c[idx*blockDim.x+idy]=idx;//[idy]; d[idx*blockDim.x+idy]=idy;//[idy];

Comment: @asma if you use `idy*gridDim.x+idx` your `c` array is 
`0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ... `and  your `d` 
`0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1`... `. if you use `idx*gridDim.y+idy` you vice versa situation. But talonmies is right about cuda columns major order.